Pre-configuring ClearML with s3 so users don't have to
When self hosting ClearML, is there a way to configure s3 as the file/artifact store so that all users's artifacts and logs are stored there in a directory structure managed by ClearML?
The structure that I am thinking of is: given an s3 prefix to the webserver such as s3://bucket-name, users by default would be routed to upload data to s3://bucket-name/<prefix set by clearml>/file.txt
I see that ~/clearml.conf can be set so that data is logged to the provided s3 path.
Since user can set the s3 path to be anywhere, it provides great flexibility but also fragmentation of data.
I am looking to see if clearml works well in a multi-user situation where users write to the same backend storage (preferably s3.)
Any info is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance
